# Rails - Running via Spring preloader in process 8773 - in my console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there when I want to `rake db:seed` in my console this only message appears

> Running via Spring preloader in process 8773

Do you how do I do to create my seed ? It doesn't appear when I deploy it on heroku master?

Here is the seed :

```
rails = Course.create(title: "Ruby On Rails")
models = rails.chapters.create(title: "Models")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "What is Active Record?", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exercise.create(title: "The Active Record pattern", content: "Exo about active record pattern")
models.items << Exercise.create(title: "Object Relational Mapping", content: "Exo about ORM")
models.items << Exercise.create(title: "Active Record as an ORM Framework", content: "Exo about ORM")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "Convention over Configuration in Active Record", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exercise.create(title: "Naming Conventions", content: "Exo about naming convention")
models.items << Exercise.create(title: "Schema Conventions", content: "Exo about schema convention")

models.items << Lesson.create(title: "Model summary", content: "Lesson content here")

models.items << Exam.create(title: "Rails Models exam", content: "Exam content here")
```

I would like save it to fix it the first course and delete it to destroy it when I finished the final version. I try to push it on heroku but the seed disapeared. Do you know why?

Comment: go to db/seeds.rb and put this at the bottom ```puts "done"```. now rerun your command to confirm seeds isn't running

Comment: It works @MilesStanfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Readme explains what Spring is the best

> Spring is a Rails application preloader. It speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background so you don't need to boot it every time you run a test, rake task or migration.

Therefore you only see this command on your local computer because Spring is not used by Heroku (or any other hosting for that matter).

Since you don't `print` or `puts` anything in your `seeds.rb` nothing appears on your screen, however it would probably be nice for Rails to let you know that it was successful!

You can always check if seed data was successfully loaded by checking what's in you database, for example

```
Course.first.title
=> "Ruby On Rails"
Lesson.first.title
=> "What is Active Record?"
```

etc.

Comment: Ok @MichalSzyndel but how can I display a real course if the seed can't do that? I have to create it in my models?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean I want to create the Course in the MVC (not in the seed) Where do I create my title and my content => in my views ?

Comment: I think you should take a look at Rails Guides http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running

Comment: I know it. But I don't understand where I named the title and content in my view. It is so difficult to explain it. I think nobody understand what I mean. The seed is different than MVC. And I create models, controller and show and index for courses, chapters, but just appears the path and not the tile and link.

Answer (score 0):

Spring preloader is only for development, it is not needed nor used in production, thus no messages about it.

Your code itself does not output anything, that's why you do not see it.

I'd advise to change to `create!` so that on error there'll be an exception and lots of output.

Comment: Thank you @Vasfed do I change .create to .create! in all create using in the seed?

Comment: @BaptisteB. yes, otherwise nothing will be saved silently, because your code does not check return values

Comment: Thank you. And how Can I destroy the seed? Do I put rails = Course.destroy?